# Map tasks get stuck while scanning hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am running a Map reduce that will scan the hbase and collect the required data. The hadoop has 7TB data and it has further 10TB free. The HBase has around 200Million records in it. While scanning the HBase after completing 99.44% 5 map tasks remain in the running state itself with 0.0% completion. These process are not at all attempted. It stays in that state forever. Hence my MR doesnt get completed at all. When ran this MR from my local machine pointing a small table it runs fine. Any ideas plz why it gets stuck and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance

Exception which I noticed in Job tracker log

```
2012-03-27 13:27:56,117 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing rack-local task task_201203271236_0001_m_000955
2012-03-27 13:27:56,699 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000865_0' has completed task_201203271236_0001_m_000865 successfully.
2012-03-27 13:27:56,699 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceEstimator: completedMapsUpdates:910  completedMapsInputSize:910  completedMapsOutputSize:60738755
2012-03-27 13:27:56,700 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing a non-local task task_201203271236_0001_m_000707
2012-03-27 13:27:56,700 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000707_0' to tip task_201203271236_0001_m_000707, for tracker 'tracker_nafhdi12809mwh.io.askjeeves.info:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:55120'
2012-03-27 13:27:56,704 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 9001, call heartbeat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerStatus@17a323c0, false, false, true, 1022) from 10.76.99.112:49072: error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.getMatchingLevelForNodes(JobInProgress.java:1235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.addRunningTaskToTIP(JobInProgress.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.obtainNewMapTask(JobInProgress.java:957)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskSelector.obtainNewMapTask(DefaultTaskSelector.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FairScheduler.assignTasks(FairScheduler.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.heartbeat(JobTracker.java:2586)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:961)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:957)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:955)
2012-03-27 13:27:56,713 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000865_1' to tip task_201203271236_0001_m_000865, for tracker 'tracker_nafhdi12809mwh.io.askjeeves.info:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:55120'
2012-03-27 13:27:56,714 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing data-local task task_201203271236_0001_m_000865
2012-03-27 13:27:56,714 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Removed completed task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000865_0' from 'tracker_nafhdi12809mwh.io.askjeeves.info:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:55120'
2012-03-27 13:27:56,841 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000877_0' has completed task_201203271236_0001_m_000877 successfully.
2012-03-27 13:27:56,841 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceEstimator: completedMapsUpdates:911  completedMapsInputSize:911  completedMapsOutputSize:60800404
2012-03-27 13:27:56,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress: Choosing a non-local task task_201203271236_0001_m_000753
2012-03-27 13:27:56,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task 'attempt_201203271236_0001_m_000753_0' to tip task_201203271236_0001_m_000753, for tracker 'tracker_nafhdi12711mwh.io.askjeeves.info:localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:46050'
2012-03-27 13:27:56,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 9001, call heartbeat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTrackerStatus@22911fb5, false, false, true, 1023) from 10.76.99.79:37228: error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out. The issue was with the topology.data file where while moving the file from windows machine, windows character got appended to the End of the line. Because of this in the getMatchingLevelForNodes() method of the hadoop code the node was coming as null and hence Null pointer exception occurred. Thanks guys for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run [`hbase hbck`](http://hbase.apache.org/tools.html) to see if there is any problem with your table

Comment: @Aron: Ran that. I am getting the status to be "OK" and "0 inconsistencies detected".

Comment: Then most likely it is something with the actual code you're running and not a problem with the data

Comment: The code scans HBase in the row ranges of 0-1, 1-2,..E-F. I am getting the output for 1-2. For 2-3 the problem starts. Hence even if it didn't produce the output for 1-2 I could have confirmed that the code is wrong...

Comment: The issue seems to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1740. Exploring more on that..